# Include vs Extend for data access

Tags: php, include, extend

This is a design question that has irked me because deep down I know I'm doing it wrong. This is not necessarily just a PHP problem, but I'm working on a PHP project now so that's where I'm coming from.
I'll just give you the scenario:
I have a JSON generation class that is used by a data access script. Basically it's the go-to URL for a website that instantiates the JSONGen class, which in turn looks at a static file and pulls the data that was requested, and sends it back as a JSON object. The file that contains the raw data has it all in array format to allow for easier reading and updating (so one doesn't have to sift through raw JSON data and risk syntax error, etc).
My question is in the accessing of that file.
What I did was to place a require([json file]) outside the class definition. Everything in the [json file] is assigned to one $JSON object.
In the class constructor, I do:

```
global $JSON;
$this->JSON = $JSON;
```

(Where $this->JSON is a private class variable).

This gives me access to the JSON from anywhere in the class, which is lovely.
It feels hacky, but I can't find anything anywhere that addresses this specific type of approach.

The problem is that once somebody decides to move the class or whatever, the only way they have of understanding the dependency of this file is in that there's a require statement in the header. Is that just how things work? Or is there a better way to do this?

**Should I use extend and put the JSON into a class (THAT sounds really stupid to me), or continue forward with my include? Or should I never, ever include a file in a class like this and rather pass it to the constructor or some other access method?**

This specific instance is a small project, and it just doesn't make sense to set up a DB for it. We can add to the file, modify the config, and the whole site updates.... so please don't tell me to switch to a DB- I'm looking for strategies for this specific problem in a more general sense.

Thanks!

Comment: So if I understand correctly the include results in an instance being created? or you create a global instance?

Comment: If you are creating a single global instance (create an instance and just calling global on that variable inside methods and such) then just turn the class into a static class. It would then be global automatically.

Comment: @jonathanKuhn that's where I was going...

Comment: The JSON data file just has essentially this:

$JSON = array();
//now add data to the array.

That's really it. I use the global keyword to gain access to the $JSON object. You see why I feel like this is a hacky approach? 
@Orangepill I flinch at saying "an instance is created" because its really just that $JSON variable being created- should I encapsulate it in a class somehow? Hmmmmmmm...

Comment: Generally though, I think the most accepted pattern in this case would be to use "dependancy injection" where you pass instances (or create them) in the constructor that saves the instance to a property of the class. This ensures that the class must have a copy of the other class to be instantiated. If you didn't instantiate $JSON and called global $JSON, it wouldn't do much good. If you pass in $JSON, the constructor can check it is valid and throw an error if there is a problem.

Comment: You can do by making static and singleton pattern . http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.patterns.php

Answer (score 0):

Probably going to get downvoted for this one but here it goes...

```
class JSON_Response {
      public static $JSON;

      // don't let people make one of these it gives the illusion that there can be more then one
      protected function __construct(){}
}
```

then in your file

```
JSON_Response::$JSON = $json;
```

and access if from anywhere as `JSON_Response::$JSON;`

and if there is anything that you commonly do to the json object (check a flag or something) you can just add a static method to the JSON_Response class.